# Nuget package targets .NET Framework and .NET Standard 2.0 but Standard projects use wrong dependency

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, .net-core, nuget-package

I have built a [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Kerberos.NET) that targets both .NET Standard 2.0 and .NET Framework 4.6 via TargetFrameworks.

```
<TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net46</TargetFrameworks>
```

The nuget config is [defined in the csproj](https://github.com/SteveSyfuhs/Kerberos.NET/blob/master/Kerberos.NET/Kerberos.NET.csproj).

.NET 4.6 projects have no problem with using this package, but .NET Standard/Core apps fail because it's trying to use the net46 build (manifests as a dependency can't get resolved). It's obvious which version is getting used because I can test a class marked internal when built against net46, but public when build against netstandard2.0 and the class won't resolve from the Standard project.

This is how the package is brought in:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Kerberos.NET" Version="1.5.821.1" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The tested code is simple:

```
var validator = new Kerberos.NET.TicketReplayValidator();
```

It will complain with: `CS0122 'TicketReplayValidator' is inaccessible due to its protection level WebApplication1(netcoreapp2.0)`

That class is defined as:

```
#if NET46
    internal class TicketReplayValidator : ITicketReplayValidator
    // snip...
#else
    public class TicketReplayValidator : ITicketReplayValidator
    // snip...
#endif
```

So the question: Is there something I can do to make consumers of this nuget package automatically use the right build? Either by modifying the package, or by specifying a target of some sort in the consuming project?

Comment: The NuGet package structure looks fine. It has two lib directories, one for net46 and one for netstandard2.0. However if I look at the assemblies - they both have the internal TicketReplayValidator class. The assembly in the lib/netstandard20 directory seems to be compiled against .NET 4.6. So presumably it is the same binary as that in the lib/net46 directory. So something is going wrong with the nuget packaging step I would guess.

Comment: The netstandard2.0 output directory does contain the netstandard2.0 assembly as well, so I think you're on to something with the packaging step.

Comment: And in fact the local build of the package grabs the right DLL too. Appears to be during the automated build.